# Error in exception handler: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: php, laravel

Error in exception handler: Trying to get property of non-object (View: /var/www/html/.../app/views/emails/soporte/show.blade.php) in /var/www/html/.../app/storage/views/d95e004dee8a72a82513c767ba381e9f:4

And this is the app/views/emails/soporte/show.blade.php

```
<html>
@if( isset( $exception ) )
    <ol>
        <li>User: {{ Session::get( 'user' )->usicodusu }}</li>
        <li>Error: {{$exception->getMessage()}}</li>
        <li>Code: {{$exception->getCode()}}
        <li>File: {{$exception->getFile()}}</li>
        <li>Line: {{$exception->getLine()}}</li>
        <li>Description: {{$exception->getTraceAsString()}}</li>
    </ol>
@elseif( isset( $description) )
    <ol>
        <li>User: {{ Session::get( 'user' )->usicodusu }}</li>
        <li>Function: {{$function}}</li>
        <li>Line: {{$line}}</li>
        <li>File: {{$file}}</li>
        <li>Description: {{$description}}</li>
    </ol>
@elseif( isset( $subject ) )
    <h1>
        {{$subject}}
    </h1>
@endif
```

Comment: Maybe you don't have any `'user'` value in the session. Try `Session::get('user', optional())->usicodusu`  or `Session::get('user')?->usicodusu` if you have php 8

Answer (score 0):

Try to give a default value if something doesn't exist, so you can see where is the problem :

```
@if( isset( $exception ) )
    <ol>
        <li>User: {{ Session::get( 'user' ) ? Session::get( 'user' )->usicodusu : 'no user session' }}</li>
        <li>Error: {{$exception->getMessage() ?? 'no getMessage'}}</li>
        <li>Code: {{$exception->getCode() ?? 'no getCode'}}
        <li>File: {{$exception->getFile() ?? 'no getFile'}}</li>
        <li>Line: {{$exception->getLine() ?? 'no getLine'}}</li>
        <li>Description: {{$exception->getTraceAsString() ?? 'no getTraceAsString'}}</li>
    </ol>
@elseif( isset( $description) )
    <ol>
        <li>User: {{ Session::get( 'user' ) ? Session::get( 'user' )->usicodusu : 'no user session' }}</li>
        <li>Function: {{$function ?? 'no function'}}</li>
        <li>Line: {{$line ?? 'no line'}}</li>
        <li>File: {{$file ?? 'no file'}}</li>
        <li>Description: {{$description}}</li>
    </ol>
@elseif( isset( $subject ) )
    <h1>
        {{$subject}}
    </h1>
@endif
```